# Excel VBA Object Required Error

Tags: vba, excel

I have been looking at this code and can't seem to figure out why I keep getting an object required error. I am trying to add a new sheet, place and array and range in the sheet (this works). Next I want to name all of the cells on the sheet a variable name to be used later. Can anyone see why it's not working?

```
    Set WS_Temp = Sheets.Add
With WS_Temp
    .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, LastColRA)) = Sheet1.Range("Dynamic_Range").Value
    .Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(counter + 1, LastColRA)) = Application.Transpose(vList)
    '.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(counter + 1, LastColRA)) = Selected_Range
    '.Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select = Selected_Range
End With

Set Selected_Range = WS_Temp.Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Value ***ERRORS HERE
```

Comment: I have Dimed WS_Temp as Worksheet and Selected_Range As Range earlier.. FYI

Comment: Can you try taking off the `.Value`?

Comment: [Don't use `.Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros), that's likely part of it. Also, don't use `Value` at the end. You just set the `Range()`, then if you need the value of the range, do `Selected_Range.Value`.

Comment: When I do that I get "Run-Time error '381' Could not set the Column property. Invalid property array index."

Comment: I have also tried the lined commented out I just posted. None of which worked

Comment: Can you rephrase what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have successfully taken an array and placed it where I want in a newly created ws. I have also taken a range and placed it in the worksheet where I want it. I know that this much works. Now I want to take all of the data on that sheet (which will be a dynamic range - sometimes more columns/ sometimes more rows) and set it to a variable name for use later.

Comment: what is Selected_Range, a range or an array? if an array, try removing the set, if a range, try removing the value.

Comment: Ultimately, later one I will use .Columns to set a ListBox equal to this variable name to populate the data into the listbox

Comment: I dimed Selected_Range as a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Can you try taking off the .Value? – Matt Cremeens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969974/excel-vba-object-required-error#comment63385923_37969974)

The `Set` keyword is used to assign *object references*. Using it to assign *values* throws the error you're getting, "Object required".

And that's exactly what you're doing here:

```
Set Selected_Range = WS_Temp.Range(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Value
```

You're trying to assign the `Selected_Range` object *the value of* `WS_Temp.Range(...)`, which you cannot do legally. Remove `.Value` and you will assign `Selected_Range` a *reference* pointing to a `Range` object returned by that `Range` call on your `WS_Temp` sheet.

Comment: I get Run-Time error '381' Could not set the Column property. Invalid property array index

Comment: @Liz no repro here, perhaps `Selection` needs to be validated first? works fine here. `Range` is a parameterized `Property Get` member of `Worksheet`; getting that error means you're giving it invalid parameters. Verify that `Selection` is in the `WS_Temp` sheet.

Comment: *assuming you're getting that error on that specific line. Avoid problems, avoid working with `Selection`, see the linked post @BruceWayne gave you.

Comment: I am getting this error later on in my code.  I will include more of my code above

Comment: @Liz ok, so the specific issue you asked about in this question is fixed, right? This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. People will google "vba object required" and land here and find what they're looking for. Please don't edit your question to add new problems every time one gets answered, that's not how this site works. Chameleon questions are very much frowned upon. Thank you.

Comment: I understand... very new to vba and this site. I will return it to it's original version.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!